# Какая-то ошибка в конфигурации MPI кластера.

Tags: компилятор, mpi

Сразу скажу, пока в этой области дилетант.

Есть "модель" HPC кластера с установленным MPI. Реально 5 узлов под VmWare (1 управляющий и 4 бездисковых счетных). Установлены компиляторы **mpicc** и Интеловский **mpiicc**.

Проблема очевидно где-то в конфигурации (а вот чего, не пойму). Суть ее в том, что программа, собранная mpicc правильно определяет "размер группы коммуникатора", а собранная mpiicc видит группу из одного процесса.

Все, конечно, началось с mp_linpack от Intel (в бинарниках), потом собирали и т.д.

Короче

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int *buf, i, rank, nints, len;
  char hostname[256];
    int size = -9999;

  MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
  printf ("size = %d\n",size);
  gethostname(hostname,255);
  printf("Hello world!  I am process number: %d on host %s\n", 
     rank, hostname);
  printf ("Bye !\n");
  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

Исполняем и видим

```
[root@manager01 tst]# 
[root@manager01 tst]# mpiicc -o miihello mpihello.c
[root@manager01 tst]# mpicc -o mihello mpihello.c
[root@manager01 tst]# mpirun -n 2 miihello 
size = 1
Hello world!  I am process number: 0 on host testnode2
Bye !
size = 1
Hello world!  I am process number: 0 on host testnode1
Bye !
[root@manager01 tst]# mpirun -n 2 mihello 
size = 2
Hello world!  I am process number: 0 on host testnode1
Bye !
size = 2
Hello world!  I am process number: 1 on host testnode2
Bye !
[root@manager01 tst]#
```

С mp_linpack аналогично, собранный mpicc (gcc) работает, а Интеловским mpiicc (icc) нет. На 100% уверен, что проблема в библиотеках, их порядке в путях (каких ?) и т.п. inconsistency. Все узлы кластера перегружали не один раз.

Никто не сталкивался с таким поведением ?

У меня даже сформулировать запросы в гугле, адекватные проблеме,  не получается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для работы **Intel MPI** библиотеки надо запускать демон **mpd** на каждом узле кластера.